# TSQL CODE to set a value for a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, case

I have a situation where I have a table with two dates lke startdate and enddate
and a procedure in which there is a variable @offset.

I need to write a tsql code for set the offset value as x when the current date falls in between the start date and enddate from the table. So I have to check the current date is in between the startdate and enddate from the table and then set the value. if not i have to set offset value as y.

I have to do that in the procedure it self.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: i was trying to write a case statement but i was not able to check current date from the entire table.

Comment: `Set @offset = Value`

Comment: It sounds to me that you are still thinking like a non-sql programmer.  What is exactly what you have to do -- it can probably be done in sql without using an IF statement.  Remember in SQL you want to work with sets not single values.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @offset = CASE WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate THEN x ELSE y END
```

Maybe try this.

```
DECLARE @OffsetTable (placeholder INT)
INSERT INTO @OffsetTable
SELECT 1
FROM Table 
WHERE GETDATE() BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate

if (@@rowcount > 0)
SET @offset = x
ELSE SET @offset = y
```

Comment: shall I declare a varibale @startdate and how can i set the values from the table to that ..thats not a single value..there are multiple start dates from which i need to check

Comment: @kris If there are multiple dates then the result being return will be more than one record. If this is the case you would need a table to hold the values.

Comment: @@Snowlockk I can use the above case statement  when i have the only one startdate or only one end date but I have lke 200 start and end dates? so how can i declare a variable and assign those dates to that @startdate.

Comment: So you have to declare two more var

Comment: @kris check the edit I did maybe this is closer to what you want.

Comment: yeah I can declare two valribles one for startdate and other one for enddate. but

Comment: No , just to count it and use a loop

Comment: DECLARE @OffsetTable (placeholder INT) what is this placeholder??

Comment: It's just a name to put the value into, it can be called anything. I'm not good at naming things.

Comment: I think you didnt get the requirement. there is table which has startdate and enddate.. there are around 200 records in that table which means 200 start and enddates. In  my procedure I have to come up with the code which can check the getdate from those 200 start and enddates and if if falls in between them then we have to set the @offset value to x if not y. I hope this made you clear picture of the requirement.

Comment: @kris when you compare the 200 dates do you set offset once or each time a comparison is done?

Comment: only once. for example in the table the start dates and end dates are in the following way 2019-03-10 00:00:00 and end date is 2019-11-03 00:00:00 and 2018-03-11 00:00:00 and end date is 2018:11:04 00:00:00. if the getdate() falls in between any of these dates then the offset value should be x else y

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
DECLARE @I Int;
DECLARE @Start Int =0;
DECLARE @End Int=0;
Set @I = Select Count(*) From YourTable;
While @I > 0
Begin
IF (GetDate() > select StartDate from yourTable where YourTableID=@I)
Set @Start = @Start + 1;
IF (GetDate() < select EndDate from yourTable where YourTableID=@I)
Set @End = @End + 1;
Set @I = @I -1;
End;
Set @I = Select Count(*) From YourTable;
If (@Satr = I) And (@End = I)
Set @Offset = X
Else Set @Offset = Y;
```

**Note:** Not tested.